# Pass an elementID through a function then return variable and use elsewhere. Possible?

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm trying to pass an element ID to a function, which then returns an edited string value to another element in my document. Can this be done?

Example below: 
grab the elementID of 'soccer' using onclick event, pass that to the function to add prefix/suffix, then pass that result to another section in the document.

```
function sportlogo(logo) {
var logo = "images/" + logo + "-logo.png";
return logo;
}

<a id="soccer" href="#selectedsport" onclick="sportlogo(document.getElementById('soccer'))">


<div id="selectedsport">
    <img src=logo;/>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `this.id` === `"soccer"`.

Comment: Sure it is possible, but currently you are not doing anything with the return value. `<img src=logo;/>` definitely does not work.

Comment: you would want to make this question more clearer and descriptive. "Can this be done?" , Yes , it is easy stuff, but you need to elaborate what you intend to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is passing the actual element into the function, rather than the ID of the element. It looks like this is what you need:

JavaScript function:

```
setLogo = function(sport){
    var img = document.getElementById("sportLogo");
    if (img){
        img.src = "images/" + sport + "-logo.png";
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<a id="soccer" onclick="setLogo('soccer');">Soccer</a>
<a id="baseball" onclick="setLogo('baseball');">Baseball</a> 
<div id="selectedsport"> 
    <img id="sportLogo" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm relatively new to JS. Thank you for your help! This works perfectly!!